# vector clear effect on reference in a loop

Tags: c++, vector, stl

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void printMatrix(vector<vector<int> >& m) {
    for (int i = 0; i < m.size(); ++i) {
        cout << "{" << m[i][0];
        for (int j = 1; j < m[i].size(); ++j) {
            cout << "," << m[i][j];
        }
        cout << "}\n";
    }
    cout << "************************\n";
}
vector<vector<int> > getClimbs(int n) {
    vector<vector<int> > first = {{1}};
    if (n==1) return first;
    vector<vector<int> > second = {{1,1}, {2}};
    if (n==2) return second;
    vector<vector<int> >& one  = first;
    vector<vector<int> >& two = second;
    vector<vector<int> > res;
    for (int i = 3; i <= n; ++i) {
        res.clear();
        for (int j = 0; j < one.size(); ++j) {
            one[j].push_back(2);
            res.push_back(one[j]);
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < two.size(); ++j) {
            //cout << "two[0] " << two[j][0] << "\n";
            two[j].push_back(1);
            //cout << "two[1] " << two[j][1] << "\n";
            //cout << "size : " << two[j].size() << "\n";
            res.push_back(two[j]);
            //cout << "size : " << res.back().size() << "\n";
            //printMatrix(res);
            two[j].pop_back();
        }
        one = two;
        two = res;
    }
    return res;
}


int main() {
    vector<vector<int> > res = getClimbs(2);
    printMatrix(res);
    res = getClimbs(3);
    printMatrix(res);
    res = getClimbs(4);
    printMatrix(res);
    res = getClimbs(5);
    printMatrix(res);
}
```

The above code works fine. But, if you observe, I am using two refereces in getClimbs(), one and two. My doubt is , I do two = res at the end of an iteration and then res.clear() at the start of next iteration. Now, since two is a reference to res, it should point to an empty container. But, that does not happen. I can access all the elements that were in res even after res is cleared.
Does anyone know why?

Please note that this does not happen if there was not a loop and I simply did two=res followed by res.clear() , then two would point to an empty container.

Comment: Are you coming from Java background? In C++ `two = res` does not mean the same thing as in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't rebind a reference variable like that. Instead what actually happened was you called the copy constructor to copy the `res` vector into whatever `two` was referencing (in this case `second`).

So you actually replaced the `second` vector with a copy of your `res` vector.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot the basic concept of re assigning the references. :)

Comment: You mean *not* re-assigning them ;)

Answer (score 1):

`two` is *not* a reference to `res`. It's a reference to `second`:

```
vector<vector<int>>& two = second;
```

References are never reassigned, so the line:

```
two = res;
```

will call the assignment operator and copy the content of `res` into `two` (an alias for `second`).

Comment: thanks. actually it ll call copy constuctor as mentioned by @Rollen D'Souza below. But I get my mistake. :)